# Synaptics Palm Dimensions numbers

Tags: touchpad, xinput

What do the numbers mean when fiddling with "Synaptics Palm Dimensions" on Ubuntu?

```
$ xinput list-props 12
.........
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (296):    5, 5
.........
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?
Many how-tos I've seen say to experiment with them until you find something that works, but even the documentation doesn't say what they actually *mean*.

Currently on Ubuntu 17.04, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are as follows:

> PalmMinWidth - Minimum finger width at which touch is considered a
>   palm
>
> PalmMinZ - Minimum finger pressure at which touch is considered a palm

Info source: ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html.

Comment: Thanks, that's still fairly difficult to understand, but if I squint I can now get my head around the concept :)